# How can we run cli commands in python while using ntest

Tags: python, command-line-interface

When i run my command using os and subprocess in the script and then test the script using ntest ,i am getting numbers as the result of the grep command even though its suppose to be names.

eg:

```
command=grep -o 'import.*' filename
out = subprocess.check_output(command,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
print(out)
for i in out:
  print(i)
```

output:

```
b'import random\nimport time\nimport re\nimport pytest\nimport Pass\nimport Node\nimport StorageAggregate\nimport Volume, VolumeClone\nimport Application, ApplicationVolume\nimport VolumeQtree\nimport Lun\nimport VolumeDoesNotExist, ApplicationAlreadyExists, \\\n'
105
109
112
111
114
116
32
114
97
110
100
111
109
10
105
109
112
111
114
116
32
116
105
109
101
10
105
109
112
111
```

Comment: It you print a single byte of a `bytes` objects. You will get the ASCII value of that byte as a decimal integer.

Comment: how do i overcome that?

Comment: Also is there any other method than using subprocess?

Comment: How to overcome that depends on what the expected behaviour should be. You did not state that.

Comment: i want to get list of imported modules

Comment: The most easy way would be to check `sys.modules` at runtime of your code or use the `-v` argument to `python`.